# AWS CodeBuild InvalidIdInRequest HttpErrorCode: 400 Error when passing credentials to Docker Runtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cdk, aws-codebuild

Following the "Unable To Locate Credentials" section from this [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-versions), I am passing `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` and `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` to Docker Runtime in my cdk code like this

```
new DockerImageAsset(this, `<id>`, {
    buildArgs: { 
        AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: process.env.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION!,
        AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI: process.env.AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI!
    }
    ...
});
```

My `Dockerfile` looks like this

```
...

ARG AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
ARG AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI

RUN export CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN=$(aws codeartifact get-authorization-token --domain my_domain --debug --domain-owner 111122223333 --query authorizationToken --output text)
...
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
2023-11-04 01:16:22,372 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - http://169.254.170.2:80 "GET /v2/credentials/<credentials> HTTP/1.1" 400 105
2023-11-04 01:16:22,372 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - Received error when attempting to retrieve container metadata: Error retrieving metadata: Received non 200 response (400) from ECS metadata: {"code":"InvalidIdInRequest","message":"CredentialsV2Request: Credentials not found","HTTPErrorCode":400}
```

How can I resolve this error?